# Meaning of $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ in basic scattering theory?

Tags: scattering, notation, integration

In basic scattering theory, $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ is supposed to be an element of [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) in the direction $\Omega$. Therefore, I assume that $\Omega$ is an angle, but what is this angle measured with respect to? None of the textbooks I am referring to give a clear indication of what this $\Omega$ is. The only relevant figure I could find is given below.

[image]

Comment: I've nothing to add to Lubos' comments, except to say that the shaded bit in the diagram (between $\Theta$ and $\Theta + \mathrm{d}\Theta$ is where the solid angle at the drawn scattering angle (i.e. $\Omega(\Theta)$ intersect the drawn sphere).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, a solid angle is something different than an ordinary angle; see ["Solid angle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle), Wikipedia.

so it is not measured "with respect to anything". Solid angle $\Omega$ measures the size of a set of directions in the 3-dimensional space via the formula
$$ \Omega = \frac{A}{R^2} $$
where $A$ is the area of the intersection of all these directions (semi-infinite lines) with a two-dimensional sphere of radius $R$. For example, in your picture, all the directions (semi-infinite lines) start at the interaction point and the relevant area is the annulus (a part of the sphere) that is dashed. The letter $\Omega$ (capital omega, the solid angle, an "O" with a hole at the bottom standing on two feet), shouldn't be confused with $\Theta$ (capital theta, an "O" with an "H" inside it) which is an ordinary angle, the polar angle in the [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates). If the solid angle has the shape of an annulus (going over all the azimuth angles $\phi$), then $d\Omega = 2\pi\sin\Theta\,d\Theta = 2\pi\cdot d(\cos\Theta)$. For an infinitesimal rectangle on the spherical surface in spherical coordinates, $d\Omega = \sin\Theta\,d\Theta\,d\phi $

You calculate its area $A$, divide it by the squared distance of the this area from the center (i.e. by the squared radius of the sphere), and you obtain the solid angle $\Omega$.

The "total" solid angle surrounding the point is $4\pi\approx 12.6$, much like the total angle in the plane is 360 degrees or $2\pi$ (in radians). The word "solid" indicates that the solid angle is a property of a solid (filled) three-dimensional body composed of all the semi-infinite lines (rays) starting from the center and going in the allowed directions; it is a generalization of the ordinary angle in which one spatial dimension is added but it is not the same thing.